# Yahoo shutting down computer

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-explorer

So here is an odd one for you.  I have about 150 computers here that I monitor, half of them get on the internet.  One of our office girls gets on the internet from time to time and does basic searches.  I have checked her history and the web filter and it is nothing out of the ordinary and she is allowed to do so.

All of a sudden now, at random, her computer will completely power off when on the main yahoo page, before she clicks 'mail' to check her email.  She could be scrolling down and all of a sudden the entire computer shuts off.

She says she does not notice it running harder (fans being loud), her programs will be working fine, no popups, no messages that its being shut off.  It has happened 3 times now and each time it was on Yahoo's site.  I replaced the Power Supply but that didn't solve it and I am not seeing anything in the event viewer.  Nobody is reporting this issue either.  She has Firefox but only uses IE.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check event viewer and see if it says anything? Does it just flat out shutdown, BSOD, or what?

Comment: Does the system event log provide any insight as to why the system is shutting down? If it's a software event it should track something in there. With hardware issues not so much.

Comment: I am not finding anything in it pertaining to the shut down.  I just see the events of it coming back on.  Nothing out of the ordinary leading up to it.

Comment: Did you verify it the CPU was overheating?

Comment: Log into the machine yourself using your own account.  Go to the same page as she does.  Witness the behavior yourself in person.

Comment: If it keeps happening on the same website, doesn't that sound like malware of some sort?